App Store Connect requires "Trader" information for EU Digital Services Act
Apple's App Store Connect has a new requirement; you must now "let us know whether or not you’re a trader" in order to comply with the European Union's Digital Services Act.


To submit new content to the App Store, Apple Books, or Apple Podcasts, you need to let us know whether or not you’re a trader. The Digital Services Act in the EU requires Apple to verify and display trader contact information for all traders who may distribute content in the EU.
Complete Compliance Requirements

It then requires you to pick one of two options:

Digital Services Act Compliance (image)
Specify if you will distribute any content in the capacity of a trader or non-trader with respect to European Union (EU) law. Learn more about whether you qualify as a trader.

This is a trader provider account

Apple will publish the verified address and contact information associated with your developer account on the App Store in accordance with EU Law.


This is a non-trader provider account

Apple will not publish the verified address and contact information associated with your developer account on the App Store in accordance with EU Law.




What is a "Trader" according to the EU DSA?
Should developers indicate that they are a trader, or not? What determines if an individual or business App Store Connect account is an EU trader?

The link you posted is quite informative. What part is not clear? IANAL, nor do I play one on TV, as the old joke went, so it would be best to take proper legal advice otherwise.
